# How to create JSF 2.0 project on Eclipse AND Websphere Community Edition 2.1

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, eclipse-3.6

I want to create JSF 2.0 project in Eclipse 3.6 and I want to deploy it on Websphere Application Server Community Edition 2.1.

I created a simple web project.

And in `index.html` I write this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
 <title>JSF 2.0</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
jsf welcome
</h:body>
</html>
```

But the text between `<h:body>` and `<h:body>` tags can not be seen in the page. How can I solve this problem?

This is buildpath:

[image]

And this is the `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>JSFApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Is there any mistake ?

Comment: Try adding facet for JSF 2.0 from the project settings. If nothing else that would add you helpful validations.

Comment: @erloewe: The facet is likely already added considering the JSF entry in the *Libraries* screenshot and the (poor) Eclipse-default `/faces/*` url pattern in `web.xml`.

Comment: @Balusc Those things were added to the question after I was around :) Just making sure, just making sure... Nice answer by the way.

Comment: @erloewe: Oh sorry, I now see the timestamps. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems:

1. You're using `.html` instead of `.xhtml`. JSF 2.0 by default resolves views on `*.xhtml`. Rename your `index.html` to `index.xhtml`.
2. You should open the page in browser by an URL matching the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`, which is `/faces/*` in your case. Thus so: http://example.com/contextname/faces/index.xhtml and not so http://example.com/contextname/index.xhtml and even not .html.

   However, I'd recommend to replace `/faces/*` by `*.xhtml` so that you (and your endusers) don't need to be surprised when omitting or forgetting the `/faces` part in the URL. The only disadvantage is that you won't be able to serve "plain vanilla" `.xhtml` files without involvement of `FacesServlet`, but this is almost never the case in real world. Rather just serve such files as `.html` then.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse 3.6 and Glassfish v3](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) (Glassfish can in this case safely be substituted)